# Assembly language taking input from user but displaying output

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, user-input

I wrote this code, it reads the data from user but did not display the output. It is written in Assembly language. I am new to Assembly language. Can somebody please help me in solving this. I shall be very thankful. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
section  .data ;Data segment
userMsg db 'Please enter a number: ' ;Ask the user to enter a number
lenUserMsg equ $-userMsg             ;The length of the message
dispMsg db 'You have entered: '
lenDispMsg equ $-dispMsg                 

section .bss            ;Uninitialized data
num resb 5
section .text           ;Code Segment
   global _start
_start:
   ;User prompt
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, userMsg
   mov edx, lenUserMsg
   int 80h

   ;Read and store the user input
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 2
   mov ecx, num  
   mov edx, 5       ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
   int 80h
   ;Output the message 'The entered number is: '
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, dispMsg
   mov edx, lenDispMsg
   int 80h  

   ;Output the number entered
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, num
   mov edx, 5
   int 80h  
   ; Exit code
   mov eax, 1
   mov ebx, 0
   int 80h
```

Comment: Works fine here. I hope you are on linux, though.

Comment: I'll ask the question directly. Are you using Linux, Windows, or OS/X?

Comment: Can you also show us the commands you use to assemble and link your code to generate an executable?

Comment: I am a windows user. and it is working now.
I followed @MikeCat answer and it workds great.

Comment: I'm surprised your code does anything when running on Windows

Comment: Yes, it was my logical error.
I was using std_error instead of std_output

Comment: @MichaelPetch Being Windows user doesn't have to mean that this code will be run on native Windows, and the tag says that this program is for Linux.

Comment: i run it on online website

Comment: @MikeCAT : I was ambiguous when I asked `Are you using Linux, Windows, or OS/X` - I meant what platform are you _running_ the code on. As for the `tag`, the OP didn't put that `linux` tag in - Jester did (as an edit). One can infer  from the code it is Linux, but we weren't entirely sure. You'll note that even Jester said _I hope you are on linux, though_. Given OPs original question, we were really not sure what the target platform really was. Some people have taken Linux code, compiled it fine on Windows and wonder why it crashed/misbehaved when executed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I read it on some websites, they say that if you want to run code on windows then you must use `global _start` before `_start:`, so i did that. I have a windows platform. So i use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In typical environments, file descripter 0 stands for standard input, 1 for standard output, and 2 for standard error output.

Reading from standard error output makes no sense for me.

Try changing the program for reading

```
   ;Read and store the user input
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 2
   mov ecx, num  
   mov edx, 5       ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
   int 80h
```

to

```
   ;Read and store the user input
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, 0
   mov ecx, num
   mov edx, 5       ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
   int 80h
```

in order to have the system read some data from standard input.

Answer (score 1):

```
section .data
out1: db 'Enter the number:'
out1l: equ $-out1
out2: db 'The number you entered was:'
out2l: equ $-out2




section  .bss
input: resb 4


section .text
global _start
_start:

;for displaying the message
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,out1
mov edx,out1l
int 80h



;for taking the input from the user
mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,input
mov edx,4
int 80h

;for displaying the message
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,out2
mov edx,out2l
int 80h



;for displaying the input

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,input
mov edx,4
int 80h

mov eax,1
mov ebx,100
int 80h
```